# What is the purpose of 1 click installation of Drupal on Web hosting?

Tags: web, drupal-7, web-hosting

I am in process of making first Drupal 7 website and for that searching for the web hosting. And I found that, several hosting says 1-click Drupal installation. But as I was searching the net for standard practice of site development, many sources explains Develop the site on local environment and then transfer to the web server (which includes, transfer of database, and whole drupal with modules) which is quite convincing that you develop locally and transfer to web so it start working there as it was working on locally.

On the other hand, what is the use of 1 click drupal installation on web server, I believe it will install the fresh core drupal, so from again initially I have to start developing, installing each module so, starting from  square 1.

1. So, which is the BEST practice for making web site live, shall i develop locally first or develop directly on web server?
2. Simultaneously, what is the best practice about maintaining site, I read that, there should be One live site where visitor will come, Second Test site which is similar to live, One local site, So what is the standard practice for this, and how to maintain?

Very thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my previous answer in point 2 i outline 4 servers: DEV, STAGE, QA and PROD. this is usually the process on kind of "biggish" company where lots of people might be working in infrastructure, development and qa department. This said, if you are not working in a complex environment, you might just have 2 drupal installations, one for testing , on DEV (e.g dev.mysite.com) and one live (eg.mysite.com). The different url can be arranged from you cpanel or personal panel in case of a shared server. 
They might run on the same server, however the dev site is the one you will be working on while creating the site, then you will clone the dev and make it live once the site is ready. 
You will keep the dev site as a space to test new features, fix bugs, test updates of module or core files. Once these new features are implemented, or bug fixed, you will replicate the same steps on the live site.
GIT is a version control system: it allow you to keep track of the code you are working on, you might want to create 2 branches: DEV and MASTER.

You will be working on DEV to create the site or update files or fix bugs, and you will merge to LIVE and pull on the live server the code once it's stable. I hope this clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

1) one click installation process are usually offered on shared servers, they then might have lower performance and memory limit that your local lamp set up. It is the good to check what is the version of PHP and MySQL that runs on the server, as well as max upload file limit or connection time. 
I prefer start working locally and then publish on my server, BUT if you install on your server first you will have a good idea of how drupal will perform in the real world, then you can always clone the site and db on your local, and also you will avoid the ugly surprise of trying to move your site from local to your server and find out bugs or migration issues.
2) in enterprise dev environment you might have 3/4 steps, DEV ("wild west")  STAGE (release candidate) QA (quality assurance server) PROD (live site). You usually sync (eg with GIT) your local to DEV or STAGE , than you push to QA, then if it's all good to PROD

Comment: Hi, this is very useful. It is very good to check the website directly on the web server environment. Moreover, 1. As I was referring to Drupal.org documents it mentions to make the One test-site and one production-site, both are on the web server, but with different url, so you can make change on test and upgrade it to production. If this will be long answer, please provide link so I can read there 2. And what is the use of Git in all these process. Very thanks in advance